# How to solve this error in phonegap -- #!/usr/bin/env node

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am getting this error when linking the library in `phonegap.js`

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2
Windows 7 Home Premium x86

Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are trying to link wrong library.

This line `#!/usr/bin/env node` means that your library is a shell script, not a JavaScript program.

Comment: Thanks the answer, i use the phonegap destokp for download the cordova files